# cakephp saveall interrupted if before save return false

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model

So maybe I am just missing something.  The SaveAll data works fine... if I take out the beforeSave or just return true no matter what everything is saved.  What I am trying to do is check if the combination of user_group_id/user_friend_id allready exists.  If it does don't save.

However it seems if you return false for one record the entire saveAll function quits running.  Maybe this is intentional?  The offical Doc is abit limited to answer this.

Obviously I could move the check to a function but this seemed better to cover every insert/update.

```
function beforeSave($options) {
        //dont let any duplicates be saved
        $count = $this->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'user_group_id' => $this->data['UserGroupFriend']['user_group_id'],
                'user_friend_id' => $this->data['UserGroupFriend']['user_friend_id'],
            )));
        if ($count)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `beforeSave()` you can check `$this->data` for invalid values and if found, modify `$this->data` to remove them.  Then return true and only the data still present in `$this->data` will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

A less invasive (and perhaps more predictable) way of doing this is to let the framework handle it for you. Instead of hacking together validation manually, just let Cake do it for you. Create a [custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules) on your `UserFriendGroup` to validate the uniqueness of these 2 fields and then the `saveAll()` method just works as usual. This is just something else to validate during it's normal validation execution.

I've linked to the custom validation rule for Cake 1.3 since you didn't specify a version, but I'm sure 2.x has something very similar.